# Sending the same primary key to 2 different databases (Mongo,Psql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I have a project of todo list and I want to create it with 2 different databases with exactly the same data. how can I have the same primary key in mongo and psql. I thought about doing it with UUID in the backend. there is a basic way to do it? sorry for this question I'm a beginner.

that's an example of my addToDo how can I have the same prim key?

```js
const addTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { content } = req.body;

  const createdPlace = new Url({
    content: content,
    enable: false,
  });
  // Sending it To Mongo
  try {
    await createdPlace.save();
    await pool.query("INSERT INTO todo (content, enable) VALUES ($1, $2)", [
      content,
      false,
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Creating Place fails mongo");
    return next(error);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
};
```